# access data attributes using simpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am using an API to get a Block FIPS number but I have not been able to target that specific number within the XML file.

I did a print_r() on the xml output and here is what I get

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [status] => OK [executionTime] => 6 ) [Block] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [FIPS] => 060730200252015 ) ) [County] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [FIPS] => 06073 [name] => San Diego ) ) [State] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [FIPS] => 06 [code] => CA [name] => California ) ) )
```

Here is the XML that is being generated

```
<Response xmlns="http://data.fcc.gov/api" status="OK" executionTime="10">
<Block FIPS="060730200252015"/>
<County FIPS="06073" name="San Diego"/>
<State FIPS="06" code="CA" name="California"/>
</Response>
```

I have been trying to get the Block FIPS Number like this:

```
$fccAPI = "http://data.fcc.gov/api/block/2010/find?latitude=$lat&longitude=$lng";
//echo $fccAPI;
$fccXML=  simplexml_load_file($fccAPI);
print_r($fccXML);
//Echo FIPS Number
echo $fccXML->FIPS;
```

Please help me target the Block FIPS number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following:

```
echo $fccXML->Block[0]['FIPS'];
```

`$fccXML` is the root node, the `<Response>` element. `->Block[0]` selects the first `Block` element, and to access an attribute, use the square brackets notation with the attribute name, i.e. `['FIPS']`.

The [SimpleXML documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) has numerous examples if you're having trouble with the syntax.